# Celery Periodic Tasks with Dynamic Arguments

Tags: python, celery, scheduled-tasks

I want to schedule a Celery task that can accept dynamic arguments at each schedule. In essence, the arguments should be derived from the results of a database query. Is there a way to achieve this?

To elaborate, my goal is to distribute Celery tasks in parallel, depending on the number of rows retrieved from a database query. I plan to divide the rows into batches, with each batch serving as an argument for a separate Celery task.

I haven't found an option in Celery's beat schedule that supports this requirement. Are there any effective alternatives to achieve this, apart from using Celery? Alternatively, am I missing any Celery-specific configuration or feature that can support this dynamic argument feature?

Comment: You can create and schedule task that queries database, creates batches and creates celery tasks on those batches. Celery serializes arguments (into json by default, but you can use pickle if you need), so you can pass an array of arguments to that tasks

Answer (score 0):

With celery task scheduler you can call the "main" task, in this task, usually in other file, you can use a for loop, get database information, etc, and build the parameters you mention. After that you call another @app.task and to this task you can send all the parameters and they all begin to execute in a parallel way, using all your processors. Only please note that you should not return data from that @app.task. Best regards.